# Stuctured binding to define constants

Tags: c++

Can structured binding be used to define a bunch of constants that would be usable in a constant expression (like a `case` in a `switch`) ? How ?

To the effect of :
`const auto [ file_type, folder_tye, sym_type ] = 42u, 43u, 44u ;`

Comment: Why don't you just try and thus find the answer much faster than the time it takes to write a StackOverflow question?

Comment: Well, you could write `const auto [ file_type, folder_tye, sym_type ] = std::make_tuple(42u, 43u, 44u);`, but I'm not sure what you hope to gain through this rather convoluted syntax.

Comment: @Igor : using `make_tuple`  doesn't make true constants : `the value of 'file_type' is not usable in a constant expression`.

Comment: So just write `const auto file_type = 42u;` and be done with it. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Why do you want to (ab)use structured bindings for this?

Comment: Didn't worked for me. `error: structured binding declaration cannot be 'constexpr'`

Comment: @Igor: because I depend on a provider who forced my `const [c1, .. ,c16] = SEQ(32,32+16)` last year to `const [c1, .. ,c28] = SEQ(42,42+28)` this year. `const [..] = SEQ(...)`, if I can achieve it, is more elegant, easier+faster, and thus safer to adapt. And also to learn about C++.

Comment: What's `SEQ`? No magic syntax would be able to produce a compile-time constant from the result of a function call that can only be known at runtime.

Comment: I might be missing something, but the example in your comment sounds a lot like what an enum does.

Comment: @Quentin : you're not missing anything, that 's exactly an `enum`. Can it be done with `auto []` ?

Comment: [Yes](https://godbolt.org/z/YqbncvP3x), but to the extent that structured bindings cannot be `constexpr` as per the answer below. But why not an enum, then ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl often questions are written not for the questioner’s immediate benefit but in order to get a question and answer written and available for future readers to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to make a structured binding usable in constant expressions due to some technicalities of how they are specified in the standard.

That seems to be intended to be corrected via [P2686](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1351), which however is currently still open and tagged `C++26` and so won't be in C++23.

With the change in the paper simply adding `constexpr` will be enough.

Comment: October was *way* too late to make C++23.